# Erotetic quantifiers?

Tags: logic, metaethics, set-theory, quantification

I can't find it, but I have a distinct memory of there being an SEP article that says something like *as if the ordinals were there before the sets* in relation to a question about whether ordinals (or at least natural numbers) are less, equally, or more fundamental compared to sets. At any rate, [the Wikipedia entry on the Lévy hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_hierarchy#%CE%A30=%CE%A00=%CE%940_formulas_and_concepts) has, "*x* is an ordinal," as a Σ<sub>0</sub> sentence whereas, "*x* is a cardinal," is listed as a Π<sub>1</sub> sentence.

This poses a design problem for me. Because I have been using a hyperoperator algebra to characterize the intended algebraic semantics of the system up to and including the initial proclamation of uncountable inaccessible cardinals therein (without, however, being versed enough in the actual method of such semantics to know whether my intent can be carried through adequately), and because the initial "numeralization" of the finite ordinals in this system is not faithful to the classical representation of 2 = {0, 1} such that 2 is the first ordered pair,<sup>♆</sup> I substituted 2 ↑<sup>*x*</sup> 2 = 4 for the axiom of pair sets. Or I at least substituted the "successor operation formula" for Knuth hyperoperators, for the axiom of pair sets, and since it is 'trivial,' given that formula, that 2 by 2 is 4 no matter what "by" means, there, I am not consternated by using, "2 by 2 is always 4," as an axiom (or close to an axiom).

In turn, I have assumed that various overarching tetradic structures that keep showing up as I go along, are examples of 2 ↑<sup>*x*</sup> 2 = 4 as a sort of principle of transfinite induction over ORD. (I know class induction is already a thing and explained in much more precise terms elsewhere; this is just how I'm 'intuitively' proceeding for the time being.) For example, I took Kant's [parafinitary](https://books.google.com/books/about/The_Long_Shadow_of_the_Parafinite.html?id=QlM8jgEACAAJ) trichotomy *finite-indefinite-infinite* and Cantor's metafinitary trichotomy *finite-transfinite-absolute* and converted them into the ***diamond of metafinity***: {absolutely finite}, {relatively finite = indefinite/parafinite}, {relatively infinite = transfinite (e.g. the individual alephs)}, {absolutely infinite}. More to the point, I have assumed that, "Which one?" and, "How many?" are two ur-questions in the system, and that "numbers" generally are *answers to those questions*, i.e. every number can be used as an answer to neither question (in other words, purely indexically,<sup>♅</sup> like an arbitrary 'name,' like a jersey number), an answer to one or the other (ordinally or cardinally), or as somehow an answer to both (this is where I axiomatize the presence of [surreal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surreal_number) (also called *surdinal numbers* at times, for the word *surd* as obliquely connected to the word *surreal*) in the system).

So at any rate, if, "Which one?" and, "How many?" are erotetic primitives in the system, then ordinal and cardinal uses of numbers are also primitives.

One way to cash this out might be to use [cardinality quantifiers](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/quantification/#CarQua), although depending on how many different cardinalities are used for the quantifiers on the axiomatic level, we might end up having "logicized" too many cardinalities (note: there is a hint of logicism in the system, an example of this being the effective merging of Fregean anti-zero with *V* (as the ZFC-style universe)). Admittedly, I am not educated enough in the details/ramifications of different concepts/theories/images of quantification to be confident about what is "at stake," here. For example, I also might want to have an explicitly *deontic* quantifier, which might be more like an example of [many-sorted quantification](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/quantification/#ManSorQua), deontic quantification being sortally different.<sup>♄</sup>

One way to ask the question of this post is, then, to go back to the beginning and ask if there are counterparts to the Lévy hierarchy for expanded/alternative quantifier systems. For now, I have only found information about the Lévy hierarchy, and no such other.

The other way to ask the question of this post is much more involved, so if you'd rather not sift through an even larger pile of intellectual sand, stop here.

**Axiogenetic quantifiers**

[Axiogenesis](https://books.google.com/books/about/Axiogenesis.html?id=JL06mAEACAAJ) is a theory about, "Why there is something instead of nothing," except Rescher actually proceeds to reframe that "Why" as, "Why are things the way they are, and not some other way?" It's been a while since I read Rescher's book so I don't remember most of the specifics, but I do recall getting the impression that the implicit deontic logic was highly axiological (of course! it says so in the title), which was why Rescher's "axiogenetic deduction" worked differently than I expected it to.

Why did I expect it to work differently? My own familiarity with axiogenetic logic went back to an argument I came up with on behalf of ecocentric vs. anthropocentric (or even more generally biocentric) environmental ethics.<sup>☎</sup> This argument was more deontological in flavor than axiological, though (reading *axiology* in place of the more common word for deontology's general foil, so-called *teleological ethics*). To this day, I also feel my argument was a little crisper in structure; but at the same time, it was not meant categorically, but hypothetically. I was not proposing that objects **do** exist because they 'ought' to, but only that because it was **possible** for them to exist because they 'ought' to, then (by some convoluted application of the Converse Barcan Formula) they actually had the ethical value they would otherwise possess if they had been axiogenetically 'created.' I.e., *if X could possibly have been created axiogenetically, then nevertheless X does actually have the amount of value that it would 'also' have had it actually been axiogenetically created,* wherefore if the inanimate, unconscious environment (of the entire universe/existence) could have been created as such, then it actually has the value it would have had it indeed been created.

At the time, this "hypothetical creation theorem" was understood all in terms of the interplay of a possibility and an actuality operator (alongside deontic operators, which were equipped with a generalization over "ought implies can" (the generalization: "may implies can" is true, too, for instance)). But in my previous post here, I went over problems I'm having with talk of actuality operators, at least in the system of logic I'm designing.

So now I'm trying to represent axiogenetic deduction as a matter of quantification. Indeed, if 'being created' is an existential state of affairs, one hopes to spell out creation in terms of quantification (supposing, that is, that "*x* exists" and "quantifies over *x*" go hand-in-hand (even the very same hand!)).

Now since I don't know enough about quantification *or* modal logic, *a fortiori* I don't know enough about quantifiers in modal logic, which I think I've heard are troublesome in their own way, there. So this is the second way to ask the question of this post: firstly, let there be a simple deontic quantifier = "There *ought to* exist *x* such that..." Then use ought-implies-can to get, "There possibly exist *x* such that..." So by fusing modal terms into quantificational substructure, do I waive the need for modal propositional operators? (And deontic propositional operators, too, then, for that matter?) Or at least, do these deontic/modal quantifiers complement deontic/modal propositional operators? And if so, is there any substantial effect on the Lévy hierarchy?

I ask about that hierarchy mostly because of the characterization of indescribable cardinals in set theory, btw. On the one hand, the set theory I have designed (and for whose sake I am now designing a system of frickin' logic) has the peculiar consequence that either indescribable cardinals do not exist whatsoever (taking deontic quantifiers for the indescribability parameters and observing that indescribable deontic objects would have no practical value, contra our assumption of the action-guidance thesis (on account of our imperative prelogic)) or the assertion that they exist is only justifiable as a theorem of some other axiom, not as an axiom itself (this set theory has lovely resources for filtering sentences on the basis of whether they can be justifiably used as axioms or not, I will say<sup>☂</sup>).

To come full circle, then: another presupposition of the system is that the ability to ask questions is the 'source' of a strong form of free will. (Unfortunately, to date, I have not been able to avoid the semblance of faculty psychology modulo our erotetic ability, which seems to be an erotetic faculty, at least as spelled out in this system.<sup>☬</sup>) The 'mathematics' of free will, in turn, are not reducible to 'mere' evolutionary game theory, say, or anything in the immediate family thereof, but are instead the mathematics of 'creative' freedom in terms of the entire possible multiverse of set theory. In other words, and adapting Kant's talk of absolute deontic value being incommensurable with instrumental rational value to the case at hand, absolute infinity is the numerical province of (strong) free will. (Note: we might cash this out in terms not of absolute and relative, but categorical and hypothetical, infinity, and say that the degree of value involved in the categorical imperative is categorically infinite.) Notwithstanding the motivation and procedure of the hypothetical creation theorem, here, we also have been assuming a highly autonomian ethics. So not only is free will the 'source' of absolute infinity (or: is itself absolutely infinite, such that it is true that there is at least one absolutely infinite reality, that of strong free will), and has absolutely infinite value, but it *is* that value, then. And so after all is said and done, so too does our erotetic faculty have absolutely infinite value, wherefore the theory of deontic/axiogenetic quantifiers has to be 'explained' or 'grounded in' a theory of erotetic quantifiers. But if the numeralization tetrad adverts to two erotetic primitives in the system, does this make the cardinal erotetic quantifier, i.e. the ur-function/ur-question, "How many?", into a deontic quantifier as well, no less? It does seem as though, if I want to preserve the effectiveness of the hypothetical creation theorem in my much more up-to-date system (that "theorem" is a "theorem" of a much less informed line of reasoning, from years and years ago), I'd do best to strengthen the relationship between quantification, existence, modality, and ought-implies-can, as much as possible, which does suggest that if the erotetic aspect of the concept of existence is such as is stated in this system, then by the deontic lights of the system moreover, yes, "How many?" turns out to be a deontic erotetic quantifier; indeed, *all the quantifiers are infused with axiogenetic force, ultimately, **are they not?***

<sup>♆</sup><sub>Instead, for starters, zero is not a set, here, not even an empty set. There is a basic function in the system designated by תּ(*x*) = (*a*, *b*), where *a* = how many "is an element of" relations *x* enters into and *b* = how many "is a set of" relations *x* enters into. (This is to incorporate the possibility of [double-extension set theory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/settheory-alternative/#DoubExteSetTheoCuri) into the system, except instead of two extensionality predicates ∈ and ε, we have an unending series ∈<sub>*x*</sub>, where *x* can be any ordinal. Granted, if it is unknown whether any form of even double-extension set theory is coherent, it is that much more unknown whether the 'theory' of the unrestricted תּ-function is coherent, but for the time being we will hope that this coherence obtains.) Now, let us assume that any pair of ordinals modulo תּ(*x*) determines a number. So there will be a number *X* such that תּ(*X*) = (0, 0). It would be unseemly, I think, if this *X* were not the number zero in my system. At any rate, the aftermath of this 'fact' is that 0 is no longer the initial ordinal. Worse, as it turns out, here, the closest thing to having 0 be the initial ordinal is having the number 1 defined as the set of a special ur-element (ur-elements are assumed for תּ(*x*) = (*y*, 0)), such that this element (a) is only an element of the 1-set and (b) is the only element of the 1-set. By 'happenstance,' this imposes a very slight filter on the Benacerraf problem: letting the ur-element be denoted by *u*, say that {*u*} = 1; then note that if we immediately proceeded in von Neumann format, we would have {*u*, {*u*}} = 2, but then *u* ∈ 2 would be true, but only *u* ∈ 1 is true. So 2 has to be {{*u*}}, here, and then 3 = {{u}, {{u}}} = {1, 2}, so that 3 is the first ordered pair instead of 2.</sub>

<sup>♅</sup><sub>In the indexical transet (here *transet* is used in lieu of *proper class* for 'aesthetic' reasons (I personally think that the phrase "proper class" sounds overly bureaucratic, if you will)), there is no ordering such as exists for the ordinals (of course), so rather than build this transet up from *u* [see the previous endnote], we can simply refer to an arbitrary *x*, and then define the expression *x*' as "other than *x*," and then have {*x*, *x*'}' as "other than {*x* and {other than *x*}}," but where at any point in the sequence, the actual number 'successively' mapped to from *x* could be literally any number besides *x*, e.g. we could start from 1/2, then have 1/2' = 59, then 59' = the fourteenth inaccessible cardinal's twelfth successor, and so on and on.</sub>

<sup>♄</sup><sub>If I knew what "sortally different" actually means, then I would more confidently say the following: have *deontic set theory* be, at a minimum, the assertion that ∃*xy*(**OB**(*x* ∈ *y*), with a transposition rule (**OB**(*x* ∈ *y*) → (*x* ∈<sub>**OB**</sub> *y*). Then have there be some תּ(*x*) = (*a*, *b*) such that ∈<sub>**OB**</sub> is the *a*th "is an element" relation. So the plural-extension side of the system might be tantamount to having many-sorted quantification anyway, and deontic quantification (or one form of deontic quantifier, at least) defined as an example of many-sorted quantification.</sub>

<sup>☎</sup><sub>My one and only philosophy professor in college was professionally focused on environmental ethics, esp. ecocentric versions: for example, in our Introduction to Ethics class he assigned Mary Midgley's, "Duties Concerning Islands," as part of our finals reading material. I was already a supporter of at least biocentric environmental ethics (on account of the environmentalism in the Thomas Covenant fantasy novels and the films/manga of Hayao Miyazaki, those two series/sets being among my favorite fantasy works) and then found ecocentrism appealing, too. At least, the philosophical challenge of justifying ecocentrism appealed to me, I guess.</sub>

<sup>☂</sup><sub>I am super-confident that I can deduce the sentence, "It is not sufficiently justifiable to axiomatize CH or, for that matter, any individual powerset equation whatsoever (aside from maybe 2<sup>0</sup> = 1)," in this system. In other words, the only set theories that are justifiable as far as CH goes are ones where CH or ~CH are theorems. On the other hand, whether GCH is justifiably axiomatizable I haven't conclusively determined yet (it seems as if it might be), though the "computation" of GCH's justification value so far seems to be such that when run through for various ~GCH options, it yields non-negligible degrees of justification for those, too.</sub>

<sup>☬</sup><sub>A basic distinction in the system is between asking a question, and displaying one. It is helpful to use a little 'parable' to illustrate what is meant by this, so imagine that you are a contestant on a game show called ["What Is the Name of This Game?"](https://cs.bme.hu/%7Eszeredi/ait/Smullyan-What-is-the-Name-of-This-Book.pdf) The way you play the game is you are given a choice between, say, four questions, one and only one of which you are to ask on your turn. Suppose, then, that someone asks *you*, "Which question are you going to ask on your next turn?" Simply *displaying* the questions in your head, or even aloud (as by saying, "I will ask the question, 'What is the perilous conundrum?'"), is not identical to actually asking the question. Furthermore, therefore, if our erotetic ability is nothing more than our ability to Benacerraf-be-damned refer to abstract erotetic objects (along the lines of abstract propositions in more common discourse), say, then the difference between asking and displaying a question would evaporate. The upshot is that now "the ability to ask questions" sounds very much like "the question-asking faculty."</sub>

Comment: Besides technical undecidability, one main difficulty of quantified modal logic is from Barcan Formula we can deduce that something possible to be created by me in the future *already* possibly exists though my creation. Another difficulty per Quine is it makes no sense to say of an ordinary object that it bears a property necessarily or contingently when the necessity or contingency in question is analytic... As for your "deontic quantifier", by default all quantifiers have some deontic valuation bias, there're many blemishes on apples, but seldom we'll quantify over them when eating apple...

Comment: As for your grounding "erotetic quantifier/primitive logic", it's an intuitively valuable one as it's nothing but the good old dialectical logic which can also have modern game semantic interpretation as successive rule-based permissible moves by defender and interlocutor. It's undeniable that the interaction of the right to ask for proofs/evidences and the obligation to give them fulfills a cycle of pursuit of truth since Socrates and other ancient dialogue-based classical verses and sutras, usually in literary or metaphoric forms. It can also be viewed as some operational semantics in CS...